# giving write permission to a user inside a protected area

Tags: permissions, users

For instance, I don't need to be a super user to write inside a `/home/username/dir` folder, yet system locations like `/usr/bin/folder1` or `/etc/bin/folder2` are protected, in that they require super user priviledges to write. But, suppose I want the directory `/usr/bin/myCustomFolder` directory to not have this permission, i.e. to write in this folder I'd like the user `customUser` to not require any super user priviledges. How can I configure this customization?

(Note: This is useful because sometimes we require writing to an SSD, but SSD is mounted on `/` for the OS, so we'd have to use superuser all the time)

Comment: This seems like what 'groups' are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the users you want this to be able to do to the same group. You can create a specific group for this task and then add each user to that group:

```
groupadd newgroup
usermod -a -G newgroup $USER
```

Create the directory you want in `/usr/local/bin/`, put your files in there and set it to that group, make it all executable:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/newdirectory
sudo chgrp -R new
```

group directory
sudo chmod 770 /usr/local/bin/newdirecory/*

and the users in that group can execute the files. And if you ever get a new user add it to the group.

In case you want to package your toolset and provide a tar you can also opt for `/opt/` (that directory is used to install third party software supplied through tar files).

Please leave /usr/bin as it is:

> `/usr/bin` is the location for the OS supplied executables that are used by common users.  Ie, not typically core operating system required files, or root user accessed files, but can be.
>
> `/usr/local/bin` is the location for all add-on executables that you add to the system to be used as common system files by all users but, are not official files supported by the OS.

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRBINMOSTUSERCOMMANDS) is used as a general method to put files in directories on Linux.